# Opening nav links in new tab

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im wanting to make the 'shop' page open in a new tab, i know you can do target: :_blank on hrefs and link_to, but I can't figure out how to set it on here. Any help is appreciated.

```html
 def nav_items
    [
      {
        url: root_path,
        title: 'Home'
      },
      {
        url: shop_path,
        title: 'Shop', target: :_blank
      },
      {
        url: subscribe_path,
        title: 'Subscribe'
      },
      {
        url: about_path,
        title: 'About'
      },
      {
        url: contact_path,
        title: 'Contact'
      },
    ]
  end

  def nav_helper style, tag_type
    nav_links = ''

    nav_items.each do |item|
      nav_links << "<#{tag_type}><a href='#{item[:url]}' class='#{style} #{active? item[:url]}'>#{item[:title]}</a></#{tag_type}>"
    end

    nav_links.html_safe
  end
```

Comment: you can't just add `target="_BLANK"`  inside the anchor tag in the nav_items loop?  Where are you looking to try to achieve this exactly, in the nav_items method?

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to use the existing Rails helpers like `content_tag` to generate the HTML elements. In addition, the usage of the `html_safe` method in that case may lead to XSS attacks if the `url` or `title` could me modified from the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `target="_blank"` in here (see the `a` tag):

```
nav_items.each do |item|
  nav_links << "<#{tag_type}><a href='#{item[:url]}' #{'target=\"_blank\"' if item[:title] == 'Shop'} class='#{style} #{active? item[:url]}'>#{item[:title]}</a></#{tag_type}>"
end
```

I think that should do ya? Hope that helps - let me know if not and I'll see if there's anything else I can think of :)

Comment: I just tried this and it is making each link open in a new tab, since it's an each do block. It works, but I want it just on the 'shop' link.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. I've updated now but can't check as I'm only on me phone. Hopefully that'll sort it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def nav_items
  [
    {
      url: root_path,
      title: 'Home'
    },
    {
      url: shop_path,
      title: 'Shop', 
      target: '_blank'  # Now a String
    },
    {
      url: subscribe_path,
      title: 'Subscribe'
    },
    {
      url: about_path,
      title: 'About'
    },
    {
      url: contact_path,
      title: 'Contact'
    },
  ]
end

def nav_helper style, tag_type
  nav_links = ''

  nav_items.each do |item|
    # Print target= if item[:target] is set
    nav_links << "<#{tag_type}><a href='#{item[:url]}' #{"target=" + item[:target] if item[:target]} class='#{style} #{active? item[:url]}'>#{item[:title]}</a></#{tag_type}>"
  end

  nav_links.html_safe
end
```